# windows batch giving error if for loop has empty variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I'm trying to do a simple if like this

```
if %REGEDIT_HOME%=="" (
    echo.
    echo Forms6i not present
    echo.
) else (
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %a in ('reg query %REGEDIT_HOME% > %LOGDIR%\tmp.txt') do (
        echo. > nul
    ) 
)
```

The problem is that since the REGEDIT_HOME is in fact null I get an error
) was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if "%REGEDIT_HOME%"=="" (
```

The match is a literal string - it must be exactly the same on both sides of the `==` to be true.

**or**

you could use

```
if  defined REGEDIT_HOME (
```

which obviously reverses the logic you've used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both ways are valid to me, but the for loop problem maintains...since the REGEDIT_HOME variable is empty, I get the error:

> was unexpected at this time.

Z:\CSP\deploys> for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %a in ('reg query "" > z:\csp\d
eploys\logs\0\tmp.txt') do (

Comment: escape it with the caret ^

Comment: Like this - %REGEDIT_HOME% ^> %LOGDIR%

Answer (score 0):

`""` is not an empty string. It is two doublequotes.

If the variable is empty, your `if` is interpreted as:

```
if =="" (
```

which gives you the error.

So you will have to check

```
if "%REGEDIT_HOME%"=="" (...
```

If the variable is empty, it is interpreted as:

```
if ""=="" (
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got past the empty variable in the IF, but the for loop problem maintains...since the REGEDIT_HOME variable is empty, I get the error:

> was unexpected at this time.

Z:\CSP\deploys> for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %a in ('reg query "" > z:\csp\d
eploys\logs\0\tmp.txt') do (